# Python - Flask API image

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, flask, yolo

I have a script I'd like to use as Rest API with Flask for image detection.
This is the Flask part witch suppose to receive and image and pass to yolo detection:

```
#initialize FLASK api
app = Flask(__name__)
#POST route
@app.route('/api/test', methods=['POST'])
def test():
    r = request
    nparr = np.fromstring(r.data, np.uint8)
    image = cv2.imdecode(nparr, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    r_image, ObjectsList = yolo.detect_img(image)
    response = {ObjectsList}
    response_pikled = jsonpickle.encode(response)

    return Response(response=response_pikled, status=200, mimetype="application/json")
app.run(host="localhost", port=5000)
```

When I use the CURL command to test passing a local image:

```
curl -i -H "content-type: image/jpeg" --data "@c:/yolo/desktop.jpg" -X POST "http://localhost:5000/api/test"
```

I receive following error message:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Dec/2019 23:30:14] "?[1m?[35mPOST /api/test HTTP/1.1?[0m" 500 -
Corrupt JPEG data: 14 extraneous bytes before marker 0x3a
[2019-12-17 23:32:08,335] ERROR in app: Exception on /api/test [POST]
File "c:/yolo/YOLOv3-object-detection-tutorial/YOLOv3-custom-training/image_detect_api.py", line 27, in test
    r_image, ObjectsList = yolo.detect_img(image)
  File "c:/yolo/YOLOv3-object-detection-tutorial/YOLOv3-custom-training/image_detect_api.py", line 173, in detect_img
    original_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.2) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'
```

I can open the file with no problem.
Am I missing something?
Thank you

Comment: As per the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga26a67788faa58ade337f8d28ba0eb19e), `If the buffer is too short or contains invalid data, the function returns an empty matrix`. I think you should check if you sending the image data correctly.

Comment: Thx, how can I actually check the buffer size? thx

Comment: Maybe by using `nparr.shape`